# Error updating photo from Android to FTP

Tags: android, image, ftp

I follow one manual to upload images from Android to FTP. If I try to update a photo that have taken I can't see anything on the FTP file. It creates and the size is ok, but contains nothing. Then i try to upload one little image and this is the result:

[image: Random image to upload]

(Random image to upload)

[image: Random image uploaded]

(Image uploaded)

The code: `class Sender extends AsyncTask
    {
    File photo;
    public Sender(File photo){
        this.photo=photo;

```
}


    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {
            ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("ftp.fercode.com"));
            ftpClient.login(xxx","xxx");
            Boolean result = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/img");
            Log.e("existeix carpeta?",result.toString() );


        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        InputStream srcFileStream=null;
        try {

            srcFileStream = new FileInputStream(photo.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            //ftpClient.stor(photo.getAbsolutePath());

             boolean status = ftpClient.storeFile("/img/imagePrueba.jpeg",  
                    srcFileStream);  
            Log.e("Status", String.valueOf(status));  
            srcFileStream.close(); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        return null;

    } 
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}`
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

That happens because I upload the image like ASCII and not binary. It's just a configuration parameter:

ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);